# How to export to excel file with FileHelpers

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I am using [File Helpers](https://nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers-Stable)  and I am unsure how to take my data and export it to an excel file.

I see a tutorial for[extracting records](http://www.filehelpers.com/example_exceldatalink.html)  but not creating a excel file.

I tried to do this

```
ExcelStorage provider = new ExcelStorage(typeof(Img));

provider.StartRow = 2;
provider.StartColumn = 1;

provider.FileName = "Customers.xls";

provider.HeaderRows = 6;

provider.InsertRecords(imgs.ToArray()); // imgs was a list before
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Excel,
>   Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Source=FileHelpers.ExcelStorage   FileName=Interop.Excel,
>   Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657
>   FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information === LOG: User =  LOG:
>   DisplayName = Interop.Excel, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase = 
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath =  Calling assembly :
>   FileHelpers.ExcelStorage, Version=2.9.9.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   machine.config. LOG: Post-policy reference: Interop.Excel,
>   Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e0c08d59cc3d657 LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL file: LOG: Attempting download of new
>   URL file:Interop.Excel.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:Interop.Excel.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:Interop.Excel.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:Interop.Excel.EXE. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:Interop.Excel.EXE. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:Interop.Excel.EXE. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:Interop.Excel.EXE.
>
> StackTrace:
>          at FileHelpers.DataLink.ExcelStorage.InitExcel()
>          at FileHelpers.DataLink.ExcelStorage.InsertRecords(Object[] records)
>          at Index() in Controller.cs:line 37
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   InnerException:

Comment: Are you referencing the office assembly in your project?

Comment: From the FileHelpers website ExcelStorage class doc...

ExcelStorage Class
This class implements the DataStorage for Microsoft Excel Files.
WARNING you need to have installed Microsoft Excel 2000 or newer to use this feature.
To use this class you need to reference the FileHelpers.ExcelStorage.dll file.

Comment: Yes, They came when I downloaded filehelpers from nuget (Interop.Excel v1.3.0.0, Interop.Office v2.1.0.0)

Comment: @dbugger - I have FileHelpers.ExcelStorage(2.9.9.0) and I have Excel 2010 on my computer.

Comment: @dbugger is probably right but I'm betting - because of the backwards compatibility - if you just reference the COM library it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add a reference to the Excel assembly in your project - it's a dependency for the software you're using to export it to Excel. You can find those assemblies under the COM tab, and here is a link that lists their [names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) so you can find them. You may not have the same version as that link but they'll be named relatively the same.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: It added for me already Interop.Excel v1.3.0.0 and Interop.Office v2.1.0.0.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the problem is that those Interop assemblies aren't going to load on your development machine because you said you're running 2010. So, you might try adding the COM references that are available for Excel, remove the two that were provided with the NuGet package, and see if it resolves the Interop as there is a lot of backward compatibility with those assemblies. In the meantime I'll see what else I can find.

Comment: I think that worked(it at least did not crash). But I won't be 100% sure till I figure out how to make it export an excel file. Do you know how to do that

Answer (score 8):

You need to set 'Embed Interop Types' to 'false' for the Interop.Excel and Interop.Office references which will automatically set copy local to true and it will all work.