# Use filehelpers without installing Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, filehelpers

Using Filehelpers I have implement a function to export some data in Excel format. However as mentioned  in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729979/how-to-export-to-excel-file-with-filehelpers), when deploying the application, Microsoft Excel 2000 or newer must be installed. Since I plan on deploying the application in a production server where there is no Microsoft Office, I was wondering whether there is a way to avoid the Excel installation.

Could it be f.e. that I could reference some assemblies that Filehelpers uses directly in my application or something like that?

Comment: As the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9730025/585968) implies, your app will be dependent on the Excel COM libraries being present.  There's no getting around that I suspect

Comment: Then use http://epplus.codeplex.com/ to work with excel without installing office.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Excel support in FileHelpers come in two flavors

- Excel with COM interface
- Excel with NPOI library

You must use the version of Excel Storage that uses NPOI library

The NuGet package is:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers.ExcelNPOIStorage/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13187464)

Comment: I agree Ole I will edit adding some background information

Answer (score 2):

The best way to read and write excel file is to use [ExcelLibrary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelLibrary/) Nuget package.

It provides a native .NET solution to create, read and modify Excel files without depending on COM interop or OLEDB connection. However, it's limited to .xls (BIFF8) files.